# Laravel Eloquent "orWhere"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use this code to check my DB to see if an item is in stock. If any one of the fields is equal to zero I want it to return zero.

```
 if (DB::table('Inventory')
        ->where('type', '=', $id)
        ->where(Input::get('condition'), '=', 0)
        ->orWhere(Input::get('memory'), '=', 0)
        ->orWhere(Input::get('color'), '=', 0)
        ->orWhere(Input::get('accessories'), '=', 0)
        ->orWhere(Input::get('carrier'), '=', 0)
        ->count() = 0)
{
    return Redirect::back()
        ->with('danger', 'This item is currently out of stock');
}
```

This is the error I'm getting: **Can't use method return value in write context**

I've only been using laravel for a few days so please bear that in mind when rating this question.

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's a legitimate noob question!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
$input = Input::only('condition', 'memory', 'color', 'accessories', 'carrier');

if ( ! Inventory::where($input + ['type' => $id])->first())
{
    return Redirect::back()
                ->with('danger', 'This item is currently out of stock');
}
```

Comment: This isn't right. You are also passing the values of the inputs in the left hand side of the where, where in fact should be the name of the columns

Comment: Wait so if it returns 0, shouldn't that mean that there were no query results?

Comment: @GabrielC.Troia - For all I know, the input values are the names of the column.

Comment: It's kind of weird but the input names are the names of the columns

Comment: The input names, exactly. Not the input values - which can be anything, since the user inputs it!

Comment: @amilajack - Exactly. If it returns 0, there were no query results for where there's no inventory. In other words, there's enough inventory in all of them.

Comment: Yea. That's why I'm returning a message that they're out of stock

Comment: @amilajack - Again, if your query count is 0, then you *do* have enough stock!

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense now. Thank you soo much! And can you please vote up my question just so my account is in good standing so I can ask more questions?

Comment: I'm getting this error:**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `Inventory` where `type` = iphone4s or `new` = 0 or `32GB` = 0 or `black` = 0 or `acc_yes` = 0 or `att` = 0)** Does that mean that the column cannot be found?

Comment: @amilajack - The way you have it set up now, it doesn't really make sense to use `orWhere`. Are you sure that's what you want? I'd think you want it to match against all those properties.

Comment: That is actually what I want to do. But I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: This is a link to an image of what my schema looks like: http://img42.com/ieLQA. Hope this helps

Comment: @amilajack - I don't see a column `type` there.

Comment: Oh man! Really sorry about that. I just changed it and I think I'm getting a similar error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'condition' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Inventory` where (`condition` = new and `memory` = 32GB and `color` = black and `accessories` = acc_yes and `carrier` = att and `id` = iphone4s) limit 1)

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because you are in fact passing the values of the input fields, instead of giving it the field names, and you also tried to assign the value 0 to the count() by having only one '='.

This should be the code:

```
if (DB::table('Inventory')
        ->where('type', '=', $id)
        ->where('condition', '=', Input::get('condition'))
        ->orWhere('memory', '=', Input::get('memory'))
        ->orWhere('color', '=', Input::get('color'))
        ->orWhere('accessories', '=', Input::get('accessories'))
        ->orWhere('carrier', '=', Input::get('carrier'))
        ->count() == 0)
{
    return Redirect::back()
        ->with('danger', 'This item is currently out of stock');
}
```

Also, why are is the 'type' suppose to equal the $id??

*Note: You can also omit the '=' in the where field, since it is the default operator, and have it just like this: `->where('color', Input::get('color'))`.

- And one more also, why, don't you use the ORM for this? Eloquent can definitely handle this type of queries.